# DynamoDB resource creation test in CDK fails when using TableV2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

Jest test fails when using DynamoDB TableV2 instead of Table:

CDK code

```js
const table = new dynamodb.TableV2(this, tableName, {
  partitionKey: {
    name: environmentInputs.partition_key,
    type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING,
  },
});
```

Test Code

```js
test('DynamoDB Table Created', () => {
  const app = new cdk.App();
    // WHEN
  const stack = new Infrastructure.InfrastructureStack(app, 'MyTestStack');
    // THEN
  const template = Template.fromStack(stack);

  template.resourceCountIs('AWS::DynamoDB::Table', 1);
});
```

The same test works when using `dynamodb.Table` instead of `dynamodb.TableV2`:

```js
template.resourceCountIs('AWS::DynamoDB::TableV2', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use GlobalTable:

```
template.resourceCountIs('AWS::DynamoDB::GlobalTable', 1);
```

I verified my stack resources using

```
cdk diff ${stackName}
```

which gave me the expected resource name.

Comment: So, you actually  created a global table in your CDK app? Was that what you meant to do?

Comment: TableV2 provides you with a CfnGlobalTable, which will act as a stand alone table until you are replica regions. Unlike the Table construct, where you are unable to add replica regions without the use of custom resources.